# Maximum sum rectangle in a 2D matrix using divide and conquer

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to implement a maximum sum algorithm that uses the divide and conquer strategy on a 2D matrix.  I'm familiar with the brute force approach which runs in O(n^6) time and Kadane's algorithm which runs in O(n^3) but how would one go about implementing a divide and conquer approach?  I've been thinking about it all day and nothing comes to mind.  In order to provide context, the brute force solution is this:

```
void maxSumBruteForce() {
    vector<vector<int>> matrix = genRandomMatrix();
    int maxSum = INT_MIN;
    printMatrix(matrix);

    for (int startRow = 0; startRow < matrix.size(); ++startRow) {
        for (int startCol = 0; startCol < matrix.size(); ++startCol) {
            for (int endRow = startRow; endRow < matrix.size(); ++endRow) {
                for (int endCol = startCol; endCol < matrix.size(); ++endCol) {
                    int curSum = 0;
                    for (int row = startRow; row <= endRow; ++row) {
                        for (int col = startCol; col <= endCol; ++col) {
                            curSum += matrix[row][col];
                        }
                    }

                    if (curSum > maxSum)
                        maxSum = curSum;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "MAX SUM: " << maxSum << endl;
}
```

Kadane's algorithm can be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-rectangle-in-a-2d-matrix-dp-27/

I figure the solution would check the four quadrants of the matrix, then various combinations of the middles.

Comment: Tactical note: Geeks For Geeks has virtually no content curation so you really have to be careful when taking advice from the site. Unless you already know most of what you are looking for you might not be able to tell the difference between the correct work of a genius and the hilarious rantings of someone who is [so wrong that they can't comprehend that they are not right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). I've seen wilder works of fantasy on Geeks for Geeks than in 40 years of playing D&D.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at but I've seen multiple sites corroborate the solution implemented via Kadane's algorithm.  I still haven't been able to make any progress with this problem.

Comment: Kadane can be reformulated as divide and conquer: https://personal.utdallas.edu/~daescu/maxsa.pdf .

Comment: Problems like this tend to be very efficiently solved with Dynamic Programming techniques.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I've seen this used for the maximum subarray problem but my problem is to find a maximum rectangle.  I really don't know how to proceed with this.

I also understand that dynamic programming would normally be the way to go but I've been told to implement a divide and conquer solution, not dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2):

One way to adapt the article<sup>1</sup> David Eisenstat [shared in the comments](https://personal.utdallas.edu/%7Edaescu/maxsa.pdf) could be the following:

If we divide the rectangle in two,

```
 -------------------
|         |         |
|         |         |
|   A     |    B    |
|         |         |
|         |         |
 -------------------
```

either the max sum is in `A` or it's in `B` or it's in a rectangle that has a part in `A` and a part in `B`. To calculate the latter, we use from each side `total_sum`, `max_sum`, `max_prefix`, `max_suffix`, for each `O(num_rows^2)` row bounds.

```
        A
 ---------------
|               |
|-----row_i-----|
|               |
|<--total_sum-->|
|               |
|max_pfx--|     |
|     |--max_sfx|
|               |
|-----row_j-----|
|               |
|               |
 ---------------
```

Then for *each window* of rows `row_i` to `row_j`, from A and B we have:

```
total_sum_AB = total_sum_A + total_sum_B
max_prefix_AB = max(max_prefix_A, total_sum_A + max_prefix_B)
max_suffix_AB = max(max_suffix_B, max_suffix_A + total_sum_B)
max_sum_AB = max(max_sum_A, max_sum_B, max_suffix_A + max_prefix_B)
```

Python code:

```py
def g(M, num_rows, l, r):
  dp = [[None] * num_rows for _ in range(num_rows)]

  if l == r:
    for i in range(num_rows):
      dp[i][i] = [M[i][l], M[i][l], M[i][l], M[i][l]]

      for j in range(i+1, num_rows):
        dp[i][j] = [M[j][l] + dp[i][j-1][0], M[j][l] + dp[i][j-1][1], M[j][l] + dp[i][j-1][2], M[j][l] + dp[i][j-1][3]]

    return dp

  mid = l + (r - l) // 2

  dp_l = g(M, num_rows, l, mid)
  dp_r = g(M, num_rows, mid + 1, r)

  for i in range(num_rows):
    for j in range(i, num_rows):
      [total_sum_l, max_sum_l, max_pfx_l, max_sfx_l] = dp_l[i][j]
      [total_sum_r, max_sum_r, max_pfx_r, max_sfx_r] = dp_r[i][j]

      total_sum = total_sum_l + total_sum_r
      max_pfx = max(max_pfx_l, total_sum_l + max_pfx_r)
      max_sfx = max(max_sfx_r, total_sum_r + max_sfx_l)
      max_sum = max(max_sum_l, max_sum_r, max_sfx_l + max_pfx_r)

      dp[i][j] = [total_sum, max_sum, max_pfx, max_sfx]

  return dp


def f(M):
  num_rows = len(M)

  dp = g(M, num_rows, 0, len(M[0]) - 1)

  best = -float('inf')

  for i in range(num_rows):
    for j in range(i, num_rows):
      [total_sum, max_sum, max_pfx, max_sfx] = dp[i][j]
      best = max(best, max_sum, max_pfx, max_sfx)

  return best
```

Output:

```py
M = [
  [ 1,  2, -1, -4,-20],
  [-8, -3,  4,  2,  1],
  [ 3,  8, 10,  1,  3],
  [-4, -1,  1,  7, -6]
]

print(f(M)) # 29

"""
  [ 1,  2, -1, -4,-20],
       -----------
  [-8,| -3,  4,  2,|  1],
  [ 3,|  8, 10,  1,|  3],
  [-4,| -1,  1,  7,| -6]
       -----------
"""
```

<sup>1</sup> *Divide & Conquer strikes back: maximum-subarray in linear time* (Ovidiu Daescu and Shane St. Luce, Department of Computer Science, University of Texas at Dallas)