# How fast can a max sum rectangle be found?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba, pythran

I need to find a rectangle in a large matrix of integers that has the maximum sum. There is an O(n^3) time algorithm as described [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/blog/maximum-sum-rectangle/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368984/maximum-sum-rectangle-in-a-2d-matrix-using-divide-and-conquer) for example.

These both work well but they are slow, because of Python partly. How much can the code be sped up for an 800 by 800 matrix for example?  It takes 56 seconds on my PC.

Here is my sample code which is based on code from geeksforgeeks:

```
import numpy as np
def kadane(arr, start, finish, n):
    # initialize subarray_sum, max_subarray_sum and
    subarray_sum = 0
    max_subarray_sum = float('-inf')

    i = None
 
    # Just some initial value to check
    # for all negative values case
    finish = -1
 
    # local variable
    local_start = 0
 
    for i in range(n):
        subarray_sum += arr[i]
        if subarray_sum < 0:
            subarray_sum = 0
            local_start = i + 1
        elif subarray_sum > max_subarray_sum:
            max_subarray_sum = subarray_sum
            start = local_start
            finish = i

    # There is at-least one
    # non-negative number
    if finish != -1:
        return max_subarray_sum, start, finish
 
    # Special Case: When all numbers
    # in arr[] are negative
    max_subarray_sum = arr[0]
    start = finish = 0
    
    # Find the maximum element in array
    for i in range(1, n):
        if arr[i] > max_subarray_sum:
            max_subarray_sum = arr[i]
            start = finish = i
    return max_subarray_sum, start, finish
 
# The main function that finds maximum subarray_sum rectangle in M
def findMaxsubarray_sum(M):
    num_rows, num_cols = M.shape
 
    # Variables to store the final output
    max_subarray_sum, finalLeft = float('-inf'), None
    finalRight, finalTop, finalBottom = None, None, None
    left, right, i = None, None, None
 
    temp = [None] * num_rows
    subarray_sum = 0
    start = 0
    finish = 0
 
    # Set the left column
    for left in range(num_cols):
        # Initialize all elements of temp as 0
        temp = np.zeros(num_rows, dtype=np.int_)
        # Set the right column for the left
        # column set by outer loop
        for right in range(left, num_cols):
            temp += M[:num_rows, right]
            #print(temp, start, finish, num_rows)
            subarray_sum, start, finish = kadane(temp, start, finish, num_rows)
 
            # Compare subarray_sum with maximum subarray_sum so far.
            # If subarray_sum is more, then update maxsubarray_sum
            # and other output values
            if subarray_sum > max_subarray_sum:
                max_subarray_sum = subarray_sum
                finalLeft = left
                finalRight = right
                finalTop = start
                finalBottom = finish
 
    # final values
    print("(Top, Left)", "(", finalTop, finalLeft, ")")
    print("(Bottom, Right)", "(", finalBottom, finalRight, ")")
    print("Max subarray_sum is:", max_subarray_sum)

# np.random.seed(40)
square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, (800, 800))

# print(square)
%timeit findMaxsubarray_sum(square)
```

Can numba or pythran or parallelization or just better use of numpy be used to speed this up a lot? Ideally I would like it to take under a second.

There is claimed to be a [faster algorithm](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/39138/1864) but I don't know how hard it would be to implement.

## Test cases

```
[[ 3  0  2]
 [-3 -3 -1]
 [-2  1 -1]]
```

The correct answer is the rectangle covering the top row with score 5.

```
[[-1  3  0]
 [ 0  0 -2]
 [ 0  2  1]]
```

The correct answer is the rectangle  covering the second column with score 5.

```
[[ 2  2 -1]
 [-1 -1  0]
 [ 3  1  1]]
```

The correct answer is the rectangle  covering the first two columns with score 6.

Comment: Since you share a link providing a C++ implementation, why not just calling it from Python if you really need to use Python? You just need to adapt the code so to operate on Numpy array (the interface can be just a raw pointer + the input shape). The C++ might not be the fastest but clearly much faster than the provided Python one. Alternatively, yes, Numba and Cython can do the job (like in some of your previous questions).

Comment: It seems the work of Takaoka and al. has been since super-seeded by Brodal and Jørgensen : see [A Linear Time Algorithm for the k Maximal Sums Problem](https://cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/mfcs07sum.pdf).

Comment: @JérômeRichard That looks very interesting. Thank you . It looks intimidating to implement unless someone here is brave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a minor update to get it to numba compile, you can get the 800x800 matrix to 0.4 seconds (140x faster). With a much heavier hand at rewriting the functions to be more accessible to numba for multithreading, you can get the 800x800 matrix down to 0.05 seconds (>1000x faster).

---

With pretty minimal alterations and using numba as you already suggested, that code can run with 800x800 matrix on my machine in about 0.4 seconds.

I swapped out your `float('-inf')` for `-np.inf` to make numba happy and then slapped a `numba.njit(cache=True)` on each function, and got that result. I may mess with it a little more to see if a little better performance can be squeezed out.

Here is the code as I ran it:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import numba

numba.config.DISABLE_JIT = False

def _gt(s=0.0):
    return time.perf_counter() - s


@numba.njit(cache=True)
def kadane(arr, start, finish, n):
    # initialize subarray_sum, max_subarray_sum and
    subarray_sum = 0
    max_subarray_sum = -np.inf

    i = None

    # Just some initial value to check
    # for all negative values case
    finish = -1

    # local variable
    local_start = 0

    for i in range(n):
        subarray_sum += arr[i]
        if subarray_sum < 0:
            subarray_sum = 0
            local_start = i + 1
        elif subarray_sum > max_subarray_sum:
            max_subarray_sum = subarray_sum
            start = local_start
            finish = i

    # There is at-least one
    # non-negative number
    if finish != -1:
        return max_subarray_sum, start, finish

    # Special Case: When all numbers
    # in arr[] are negative
    max_subarray_sum = arr[0]
    start = finish = 0

    # Find the maximum element in array
    for i in range(1, n):
        if arr[i] > max_subarray_sum:
            max_subarray_sum = arr[i]
            start = finish = i
    return max_subarray_sum, start, finish


# The main function that finds maximum subarray_sum rectangle in M

@numba.njit(cache=True)
def findMaxsubarray_sum(M):
    num_rows, num_cols = M.shape

    # Variables to store the final output
    max_subarray_sum, finalLeft = -np.inf, None
    finalRight, finalTop, finalBottom = None, None, None
    left, right, i = None, None, None

    temp = [None] * num_rows
    subarray_sum = 0
    start = 0
    finish = 0

    # Set the left column
    for left in range(num_cols):
        # Initialize all elements of temp as 0
        temp = np.zeros(num_rows, dtype=np.int_)
        # Set the right column for the left
        # column set by outer loop
        for right in range(left, num_cols):
            temp += M[:num_rows, right]
            # print(temp, start, finish, num_rows)
            subarray_sum, start, finish = kadane(temp, start, finish, num_rows)

            # Compare subarray_sum with maximum subarray_sum so far.
            # If subarray_sum is more, then update maxsubarray_sum
            # and other output values
            if subarray_sum > max_subarray_sum:
                max_subarray_sum = subarray_sum
                finalLeft = left
                finalRight = right
                finalTop = start
                finalBottom = finish

    # final values
    if True:
        print("(Top, Left)", "(", finalTop, finalLeft, ")")
        print("(Bottom, Right)", "(", finalBottom, finalRight, ")")
        print("Max subarray_sum is:", max_subarray_sum)


def _main():
    # First loop may have numba compilations
    #   second loop shows true-er performance
    for i in range(2):
        rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
        N = 800
        square = rng.integers(-3, 4, (N, N))
        s = _gt()
        findMaxsubarray_sum(square)
        print(f'Run time: {N},{_gt(s):8.6f}\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

And here is the result I got:

```
(Top, Left) ( 26 315 )
(Bottom, Right) ( 256 798 )
Max subarray_sum is: 1991.0
Run time: 800,1.262665

(Top, Left) ( 26 315 )
(Bottom, Right) ( 256 798 )
Max subarray_sum is: 1991.0
Run time: 800,0.379572
```

---

And with a major rewrite, taking out most of the variables, getting rid of the if statements in `findMaxsubarray_sum` function, and parallelizing the outer most loop (`for left in ...`), I got the average run time down to 0.05 seconds for the 800x800. I can't figure out how to optimize the loop in `kadane`, and none of my test cases hit the all negatives fall through, so I didn't touch that block.

This one was tested with 25 randomly generated test cases using the original code as the baseline. (The issue in the prior version of this was how the variable `out_sum_arr` was created, as I had used `numpy.empty` thinking it would be fasted, but it really needed to be actually filled with valid values, so it now uses `numpy.full` to address that issue.)

Here is that code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import numba

numba.config.DISABLE_JIT = False


def _gt(s=0.0):
    return time.perf_counter() - s


@numba.njit(cache=True)
def kadane(arr, n):
    # initialize subarray_sum, max_subarray_sum and
    subarray_sum = 0
    max_subarray_sum = np.int32(-2147483648)

    # Just some initial value to check
    # for all negative values case
    finish = -1

    # local variable
    local_start = 0

    for i in range(n):
        subarray_sum += arr[i]
        if subarray_sum < 0:
            subarray_sum = 0
            local_start = i + 1
        elif subarray_sum > max_subarray_sum:
            max_subarray_sum = subarray_sum
            start = local_start
            finish = i

    # There is at-least one
    # non-negative number
    if finish != -1:
        return max_subarray_sum, start, finish

    # raise AssertionError('Untested code block')
    # Special Case: When all numbers
    # in arr[] are negative
    max_subarray_sum = arr[0]
    start = finish = 0
    # Find the maximum element in array
    for i in range(1, n):
        if arr[i] > max_subarray_sum:
            max_subarray_sum = arr[i]
            start = finish = i
    return max_subarray_sum, start, finish


# The main function that finds maximum subarray_sum rectangle in M
@numba.njit(cache=True, parallel=True)
def findMaxsubarray_sum(M):
    num_rows, num_cols = M.shape

    out_pos_arr = np.empty((num_cols * num_cols, 4), dtype=np.int32)
    out_sum_arr = np.full((num_cols * num_cols,), np.int32(-2147483648), dtype=np.int32)

    # Set the left column
    for left in numba.prange(num_cols):
        # Initialize all elements of temp as 0
        temp = np.zeros(num_rows, dtype=np.int_)
        # Set the right column for the left
        # column set by outer loop
        for right in range(left, num_cols):
            temp += M[:num_rows, right]
            subarray_sum, start, finish = kadane(temp, num_rows)
            out_sum_arr[left * num_cols + right] = subarray_sum
            out_pos_arr[left * num_cols + right, :] = np.array((left, right, start, finish))
    max_pos = np.argmax(out_sum_arr)
    finalLeft, finalRight, finalTop, finalBottom = out_pos_arr[max_pos]
    max_subarray_sum = out_sum_arr[max_pos]

    return finalTop, finalLeft, finalBottom, finalRight, max_subarray_sum


def _main():
    # First loop may have numba compilations
    #   second loop shows true-er performance
    run_sum = 0.0
    loop_count = 10
    for i in range(loop_count):
        rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
        N = 800
        # N = 1700
        square = rng.integers(-3, 4, (N, N), dtype=np.int32)
        # square = rng.integers(-30, -4, (N, N))
        s = _gt()
        finalTop, finalLeft, finalBottom, finalRight, max_subarray_sum = findMaxsubarray_sum(square)
        run_time = _gt(s)
        print(f'Run time: {N},{run_time:8.6f}')
        # Don't count numba compilation time
        if i > 0:
            run_sum += run_time
        if False:
            print("(Top, Left)", "(", finalTop, finalLeft, ")")
            print("(Bottom, Right)", "(", finalBottom, finalRight, ")")
            print("Max subarray_sum is:", max_subarray_sum)
            print()

    print(f'Average speed: {run_sum / (loop_count - 1):.5f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

And here is the output it gave me:

```
Run time: 800,2.169412
Run time: 800,0.051767
Run time: 800,0.046097
Run time: 800,0.048518
Run time: 800,0.047188
Run time: 800,0.050306
Run time: 800,0.050326
Run time: 800,0.049614
Run time: 800,0.050655
Run time: 800,0.049150
Average speed: 0.04929
```

Comment: Thank you. Any extra speed would be really good as then maybe I can run 1000 by 1000 as well..

Comment: @Simd I got you. The latest edit I just put up can do a 1700x1700 array in 1 second. Enjoy!

Comment: I think there might be a bug,  If  I set N = 100 then I get (Top, Left) ( -1900753008 0 )
(Bottom, Right) ( 22071 0 ). But actually the output is also not consistent between runs.  I also get (Top, Left) ( 0 0 )
(Bottom, Right) ( 0 0 )
Max subarray_sum is: 2053722980.

Comment: I have added some simple test cases. Your faster code currently does not give the right answers for them.

Comment: @Simd I made a 25 test cases of various sizes using your code and verified that it doesn't always work, though the first version up above does appear to work, and already meets your original request. I will poke around to see if I can fix the bottom one, but may not be able to. I'll edit it to remove the second version until/unless I can get a working update. Good catch!

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope it can be fixed as it was very fast.

Comment: @Simd I updated it, and this one is tested a bit better. Let me know if you find any issues in this one!

Comment: This is an awesome speedup . Thank you.